# jquery getting parameters from url leaves also url in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function (from [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery))

to get parameters from the url:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine, but when I console.log a variable, I get the value but also the url is attached.

So for instance for address: http://dummy.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample   I do:

var tech = getUrlParameter('technology');
and in console log I get:

```
jquery     ?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample
```

Through jQuery I'm setting the value of the  field and the problem is that the whole string is attached. How to make this right? (I want only 'jquery' to be attached and appear in console log)

Comment: Offtopic: `window` is excess in `window.location`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that

```
function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = {}, hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
```

then

```
urlVars = getUrlVars()
```

in urlVars you find a key/value hash, print that out ;)

```
console.log(urlVars)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried some similar scripts, but I still get the same result. Maybe there's something wrong in my application or sth :(

Comment: O.K. there is something wrong with my further scripting, your solution can be the answer to my question so I can accept is. Thanks for the support

Comment: Why
`window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)`
is better than
`location.search.substring(1)` ?

Comment: same result ;) I paste the first rapidly idea. location.search.substring(1) is better :)